# Populate div depending on JS arg

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm new to JS and I'm trying to create a function that takes the prices and discount prices (calculated in the function) of 3 different products and populates prices into a different div for each product.

I'd like to take the product as an arg and then set variables to different values depending on the product name that I passed in.

So far, this is what I've got:

```
function getProductDiscount(product1, product2, product3) {

    var MSRPs = "";
    var MSRP = "";
    var listPrices = "";
    var listPrice = "";

    var productMSRP = "";

    if (product1) {

        productMSRP = $(".product1MSRP");

        // product1 MSRP depending on currency
        MSRPs = {"USD": 12.34, "CAD": 56.78, "GBP": 91.23};
        MSRP = MSRPs["{{ order.currency }}"];
        listPrices = {"USD": 22.34, "CAD": 66.78, "GBP": 111.23};
        listPrice = listPrices["{{ order.currency }}"];
    } if (product2) {

        productMSRP = $(".product2MSRP");

        // product2 MSRP depending on currency
        MSRPs = {"USD": 32.33, "CAD": 44.44, "GBP": 55.55};
        MSRP = MSRPs["{{ order.currency }}"];
        listPrices = {"USD": 66.66, "CAD": 77.77, "GBP": 88.88};
        listPrice = listPrices["{{ order.currency }}"];
    } if (product3) {

        productMSRP = $(".product3MSRP");

    // product3 MSRP depending on currency
        MSRPs = {"USD": 77.88, "CAD": 88.99, "GBP": 99.99};
        MSRP = MSRPs["{{ order.currency }}"];
        listPrices = {"USD": 111.99, "CAD": 122.99, "GBP": 133.99};
        listPrice = listPrices["{{ order.currency }}"];
    }

   $(".productSave").text(formatCurrencySym(MSRP - listPrice, "{{ order.currency }}"));

    productMSRP.text(formatCurrencySym(MSRP, "{{ order.currency }}"));

    $(".productDiscountPercent").text(Math.round((MSRP - listPrice) / MSRP * 100 / 5) * 5 + "%");

}


getProductDiscount(name1, name2, name3);
```

So far, only the third prices are populating the div. I know this is because it's reading that one last, but I'm unsure how to populate the classes ".productFooMSRP" with their respective values.

** Edit** Here is the HTML of the divs I'm trying to populate with the prices (there are 2 of these on the page) one is ".product1MSRP" the other is ".product3MSRP":

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 product-text">
     <img src="img.png" class="productImage">
          <div class="text-center">
              <p>{% trans "MSRP" %} <span class="product3MSRP"></span></p>
              <p class="red">{% trans "On Sale!" %}</p>
               <a role="button" href="" class="btn btn-default discountButton" role="button">
               {% blocktrans %}Get a <span class="productDiscountPercent">{% endblocktrans %}</span>
{% blocktrans %}Discount{% endblocktrans %}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: what about this doesn't work?

Comment: It's only populating one of the divs with the latter values. For example: I have 2 divs on the page: product1 that should have it's respective values, and product3. It's only populating product3's values.

Comment: can you show some of your html as well?

Comment: I've added the html for one of the divs (its exactly the same for each product except the product class name that I'm trying to populate changes changes)

Comment: In your html example there is no productSave class.
Is there any further information about that element that javascript should edit?

Comment: @GiacomoPenuti the productSave class is not necessary for this question. I'm concerned mainly about the productDiscoutPercent and mainly productFooMSRP classes. Apologies if that's unclear.

Comment: There is a misstype `</strong` in html 5th line, also a " %}" is missing on the same line.
About the  `$(".productSave").text(formatCurrencySym(MSRP - listPrice, "{{ order.currency }}"));`
, if it does not concern the question, please remove it from your code example cause that will result in js error.

Comment: @GiacomoPenuti thank you for noticing that. I've edited that part out. Any ideas about how to get this working? I'm still stumped and it's still only populating the second div.

Comment: I will have a look asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are my purposes:

1)"Just make it work" - edited what your function does to achive your result on your already tracked path

```
    function getProductDiscount(product1, product2, product3) {

      var MSRPs = "";
      var MSRP = "";
      var listPrices = "";
      var listPrice = "";

      var productMSRP = "";

      if (product1) {

        productMSRP = $(".product1MSRP");

        // product1 MSRP depending on currency
        MSRPs = {
          "USD": 12.34,
          "CAD": 56.78,
          "GBP": 91.23
        };
        MSRP = MSRPs["{{ order.currency }}"];
        listPrices = {
          "USD": 22.34,
          "CAD": 66.78,
          "GBP": 111.23
        };
        listPrice = listPrices["{{ order.currency }}"];

        //price show moved here
        productMSRP.text(formatCurrencySym(MSRP, "{{ order.currency }}"));
        //edited to match the specific product div 
        productMSRP.prev().parent().find(".productDiscountPercent").text(Math.round((MSRP - listPrice) / MSRP * 100 / 5) * 5 + "%");

      }
      if (product2) {

        productMSRP = $(".product2MSRP");

        // product2 MSRP depending on currency
        MSRPs = {
          "USD": 32.33,
          "CAD": 44.44,
          "GBP": 55.55
        };
        MSRP = MSRPs["{{ order.currency }}"];
        listPrices = {
          "USD": 66.66,
          "CAD": 77.77,
          "GBP": 88.88
        };
        listPrice = listPrices["{{ order.currency }}"];

        //price show moved here
        productMSRP.text(formatCurrencySym(MSRP, "{{ order.currency         }}"));
        //edited to match the specific product div 
        productMSRP.parent().parent().find(".productDiscountPercent").text(Math.round((MSRP - listPrice) / MSRP * 100 / 5) * 5 + "%");

      }
      if (product3) {

        productMSRP = $(".product3MSRP");

        // product3 MSRP depending on currency
        MSRPs = {
          "USD": 77.88,
          "CAD": 88.99,
          "GBP": 99.99
        };
        MSRP = MSRPs["{{ order.currency }}"];
        listPrices = {
          "USD": 111.99,
          "CAD": 122.99,
          "GBP": 133.99
        };
        listPrice = listPrices["{{ order.currency }}"];

        //price show moved here
        productMSRP.text(formatCurrencySym(MSRP, "{{ order.currency }}"));

        //edited to match the specific product div 
        productMSRP.parent().parent().find(".productDiscountPercent").text(Math.round((MSRP - listPrice) / MSRP * 100 / 5) * 5 + "%");

      }

      //ignored
      //$(".productSave").text(formatCurrencySym(MSRP - listPrice, "{{ order.currency }}"));

    }

    getProductDiscount(true, false, true);
```

As you can see on the function call, it doesn't expect any parameter but what products are gonna be shown.

https://jsfiddle.net/df9h6dub/

2)**"Proactive"** - IMHO the whole code has to be revised to make it more simple and flexible.

```
    function getProductDiscount(productMSRP, MSRPs, listPrices) {
      var MSRP = "";
      var listPrice = "";

        MSRP = MSRPs["{{ order.currency }}"];
        listPrice = listPrices["{{ order.currency }}"];
        productMSRP.text(formatCurrencySym(MSRP, "{{ order.currency }}"));
        //edited to match the specific product div 
        productMSRP.parent().parent().find(".productDiscountPercent").text(Math.round((MSRP - listPrice) / MSRP * 100 / 5) * 5 + "%");

    }


    //product1 parameters and function call
    p1MSRPel = $(".product1MSRP");

        p1MSRPs = {
          "USD": 12.34,
          "CAD": 56.78,
          "GBP": 91.23
        };
        p1listPrices = {
          "USD": 22.34,
          "CAD": 66.78,
          "GBP": 111.23
        };

    getProductDiscount(p1MSRPel, p1MSRPs, p1listPrices);


    //product3 parameters and function call
    p3MSRPel = $(".product3MSRP");

        p3MSRPs = {
          "USD": 77.88,
          "CAD": 88.99,
          "GBP": 99.99
        };
        p3listPrices = {
          "USD": 111.99,
          "CAD": 122.99,
          "GBP": 133.99
        };

    getProductDiscount(p3MSRPel, p3MSRPs, p3listPrices);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I looked at your jsfiddle and although it's populating both product MSRPs, it's repeating product3MSRP in both instances. Rather than injecting product1MSRP (12.34) it is injecting product3MSRP (111.99). This is the problem I'm having currently with my code since posting op. Will try your second suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome!This is due to a faked function I created to make the fiddle work. Please read comments in JS. And please read both options.